# How do I get my D-link DWA - 131 to work on Pop!_OS?

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules

I'm new to Linux, and I've just installed Pop!_OS. I'm on a desktop and my DWA - 131 doesn't connect to any networks. How do I fix this?

Comment: DWA - 131: The chip = rtl8192eu https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/linux-firmware/filelist ..... Is `linux-firmware` installed ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Sorry, new to linux and all.

Comment: If this package is included in PopOS : `sudo apt install linux-firmware` ..... Please read the above liked file list, to find "rtl8192eu".